# 2 compile errors on qt5 project

Tags: c++, qt

I’m translating a project from qt4 to qt5, and already updated most of the differences.
when i’m compiling, i get the following two errors from the compiler inside the sal.h include file, in line number 2367.

the line is:

extern “C” {…

the errors are:
c2144: syntax error : int should be preceded by ‘;’
c4430: missing type specifier – int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default int

i didn’t find this error in all of the forums that talks about translating from qt4 to qt 5.1.1.
on qt4 it worked well.

does someone know whats wrong?

Comment: Show line that goes before.

Comment: Please provide a simple test case. It is impossible to help with this much information.